# Windows CMD how to bypass the confirmation prompt if windows is installed in an other langueages

Tags: windows, cmd, registry

so I'm trying to add registry value and the echo y| allows me to update it (overwrite it)when it already exists as it already sends the y(yes) command. I recently tested it with some of my friends and one has noticed that the command prompt bugged out spamming, turns out as his windows installation is not English it won't recognize the Y as yes (as he has to write yes in he's language or its starting letter). Is there a Universal way to pick yes or a workaround to make it use "Echo I|" if his computer is in that other language if the first code didn't work?

```
echo y | reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v UsageMonitorStartup /t REG_SZ /d "\"%var%\MonitorUpdate.exe\"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to bypass the confirmation prompt.  If that's the case, just pass the `/f` parameter to the command line, to "force overwriting the existing registry entry without prompt."

So instead of this:

```
echo y | reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v UsageMonitorStartup /t REG_SZ /d "\"%var%\MonitorUpdate.exe\
```

Just do this:

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /f /v UsageMonitorStartup /t REG_SZ /d "\"%var%\MonitorUpdate.exe\
```